# I have python code for calling api and i want to use it in Azure Data lake analytics to get the Json file using that python code

Tags: azure, analytics

what I want is I want to call the auth2 api for a site in azure data lake analytics using python.
I have the python code for doing that but I dnt know how to get it integrated with ADLA

Comment: Could you please clarify your query?

Comment: So i have python code to call api's I want to ue it in Azure data lake analytics.

Comment: Are you using Azure Data Lake Gen1 or Gen2?

Comment: Azure Data Lake Gen1